# Convert <br> to plain text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a sample html text:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>This is test<br>THIS IS TEST</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now i want to get output like this to paste into excel

This is sample test`<br>`THIS IS TEST ( i want to get `<br>` tag like a string )

Because i want to get all content in `<p>` tag, include all `<br>` tag.

How can i do that ?

Thank for read.

Comment: Hi Jenson, If you think this is an answer, please try to post as answer instead of writing in comment.

Comment: @MusakkhirSayyed It's juz tiny mince of code. No need to post as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) should do what you need.

```
var content = $('p').html();
```

will give you:

```
This is test<br>THIS IS TEST
```

See example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6v5sxpnk/)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use jquery, the simplest way to get the result is use "`html()`" function.

```
var htmlcontent = $('body').html();
alert(htmlcontent );
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery, do it just with JavaScript:

```
alert(document.getElementsByTagName('p').innerHTML;)
```

Or if you want have more p tags:

```
var parag = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for(var i=0; i<parag.length; i++)
{
    alert(parag[i].innerHTML);
}
```